# clone select box in 5 number of times jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

if click on add button clone select box in 5 number of times jquery

```js
$('.clkadd').click(function() {
  $('.twoselect:last').clone().appendTo('.appendtwo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="twoloop">
  <select class="twoselect"><option>element</option><option>Next Level</option></select>
  <div class="addbtn"><a href="#" class="clkadd">Add</a></div>
  <div class='appendtwo'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you want to restrict it to be cloned only 5 times?

Comment: yes  restrict only 5 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could restrict the click with count of the click below 5

```js
var c=0;
$('.clkadd').click(function() {
if(c<5){
  $('.twoselect:last').clone().appendTo('.appendtwo');
  }
  c++
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="twoloop">
  <select class="twoselect"><option>element</option><option>Next Level</option></select>
  <div class="addbtn"><a href="#" class="clkadd">Add</a></div>
  <div class='appendtwo'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property returns the no of elements in DOM. Use it in the condition to restrict the elements to be cloned.

```js
$('.clkadd').click(function() {
  var select = $('.twoselect');
  if (select.length <= 5) {
    select.filter(':last').clone().appendTo('.appendtwo');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="twoloop">
  <select class="twoselect"><option>element</option><option>Next Level</option></select>
  <div class="addbtn"><a href="#" class="clkadd">Add</a></div>
  <div class='appendtwo'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `<= 5` as you can only have 4 selects at the moment